# Standard chatter escalation class showing code coverage is 0

Tags: apex

Below is the chatter answer escalation class, which passed successfully but showing code coverage is 0. Please suggest why it is showing code coverage 0 ?

```
@isTest 
private class ChatterAnswersEscalationTriggerTest { 
  static testMethod void validateQuestionEscalation() { 
    String questionTitle = 'questionTitle'; 
    String questionBody = 'questionBody'; 
    Community[] c = [SELECT Id FROM Community WHERE name = '']; 
    system.debug('*** COMMUNITY ID' + c); 
    // We cannot create a question without a community 
    if (c.size() == 0) { return; } 
      String communityId = c[0].Id; 
      system.debug('COMMID' + communityId); 
      Question q = new Question(); 
      q.Title = questionTitle; 
      q.Body = questionBody; 
      q.CommunityId = communityId; 
      system.debug('***Q' + q); 
      insert(q); 
      q.Priority = 'high'; 
      update(q); 
      Case ca = [SELECT Origin, CommunityId, Subject, Description from Case where QuestionId =: q.Id]; 
      // Test that escaltion trigger correctly escalate the question to a case 
      System.assertEquals(questionTitle, ca.Subject); 
      System.assertEquals(questionBody, ca.Description); 
      System.assertEquals('Chatter Answers', ca.Origin); 
      System.assertEquals(communityId, ca.CommunityId); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here you are not inserting any test data and you are getting `0` records and `if (c.size() == 0) { return; }` skips rest of the code execution that's why it's not covering any code; so before getting any data in to test add some data then get it;

```
List<Community> dataToInsert = new List<Community>();
for(Integeer i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  dataToInsert.add(new Community(Name = ''));
}
insert dataToInsert;
```

Now add rest of the code;